# magento setup configuration plugin

Tags: magento

Is it posible to create or maybe there are alredy some extension or file where you can make all backend configurations? 
e.g. add/rename storeviews, websites, set shipping method add category/product attributes, build category trees etc.

I'm working with a lot of magento projects and it would be crazy helpful for me to have such extension where you can add all configuration in one to five files and just install it via "Magento Connect Manager". Meanwhile it would be helpful for customer if i could send config *.zip with all config that needs to be set.

Comment: Hi, this is a fair question but as a plugin request, it's off-topic on Stack Overflow. I would check out Magento's community support resources

Comment: I know. already searched for this - no luck. I just hoped that experts and devs surfing in here coul give me a clue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating queries to update the `core_config_data` table in your database.

The `core_config_data table` contains all the settings under `System - Configuration` in the backend.

This is what I do when I import a production database in my local development environment. I just update the config settings (like baseurl) with a sql query script.